# How to use Arraylist to put elements of list<list<Character>> in to a single list in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want to ask how to achieve this:
input: List <list >, output: list of character. Example: ( (a,b), (f,g),(),(k))--->(a,b,&,f,g,&,&,k)
between two lists, there should be a &, such as ((a,b),(f,g))--->(a,b,&,f,g), if the list if (), then as example ((f,g),(),(k))-->(f,g,&,&,k) there are two &,&, because between (f,g),()there should put a &, and between (),(k) there should put a &.  (I have already learnt how to check exceptions, but get stuckt for long time to solve this part of task)
my code:

```
Suppose P stand of List<List<Character>>
public class HandleListofLists {
public List<Character> exe1 (P a) throws Exception{
if(a == null){
throw new Exception("a is null");
}

// what to do as next step, I have no idea

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```java
static List<Character> exe1(List<List<Character>> a) {
    return a.stream()
        .flatMap(x -> Stream.concat(Stream.of('&'), x.stream()))
        .skip(1)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(exe1(List.of( List.of('a','b'), List.of('f','g'), List.of(), List.of('k') )));
```

*Output*

```
[a, b, &, f, g, &, &, k]
```

Comment: Thank you! May I ask you for a suggestion: If I want to review this topic in java, should I review stream? or list of list? I am trying to looking for " list of list" , but the search result is always about LinkedList.　After I see your way to solve this question, I think I should learn about stream. I am not sure what I should review. Thanks in advance:D

Comment: @twoStones *"I think I should learn about stream"* Good thought, go for it. --- *"I am not sure what I should review"* Streams.

Comment: @Andreas , isn't it possible to change order Stream.of('&'),x.stream()) . I tried that and not able to get rid of last '&' . Is that the reason you inverted the order and used  skip(1) .

Comment: @Knowledge_seeker I didn't *invert* the order, I *chose* the order that made it **easy** to remove the extraneous element. To *invert* something requires that it already exists, and since I wrote the code from scratch, there was nothing to "invert". --- It is always easier to remove the *first*, since you can easily tell when you're handling the *first*, but you might not know you're handling the *last* when you do, since you might not know it was the *last* until you go look for the *next* element. Sure, you can remove the last after the fact, but that would require saving the list.